# How many sajdas are in Quran?

Tags: quran, sajda

**Questions**:

1. How many sajda are there in Quran?
2. And which para they are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of Sajdah in the Qur'an which are as followings:

**1. Vajib (obligatory)**. The ayas which have Vajib Sajdah are:

Surah Sajdah:  32:15«وَ لا یسْتَکبِرُونَ»

Surah Fusilah: 41:37«اِیاهُ تَعْبُدُونَ»

Surah Al-Najm: 53:62

Surah al-Alaq: 96:19

**2. Mustahab (recommended).** The ayas which have Mustahab Sajadah are:

Surah Al-Araf:       7:206 «وَ لَهُ یسْجُدُونَ»

Surah Al-Ra'd:       13:15«وَ ظِلالَهُمْ بِالغُدُوِّ وُ الْاصالِ»

Surah al-Nahl:       16:49,50«وَ یفْعَلُونَ ما یؤْمَرُونَ»

Surah Bani Isreal:   17:107-109«وَ یزِیدُهُمْ خُشُوعاً»

Surah Maryam:        19:58«خَرُّوا سُجَّداً وَ بُکیا»

Surah Haj:           22:18,77«یفْعَلُ ما یشاءُ»و «وَ افْعَلُوا الْخَیرَ»

Surah Forqan:        25:60«وَ زادَهُمْ نُفُوراً»

Surah Al-Naml:       27:25,26«رَبُّ الْعَرْشِ الْعَظِیمِ»

Surah Sad:           38:24«وَ خَرَّ راکعاً وَ أَنابَ»

Surah Inshiqaq:      84:21«إِذا قُرِئَ»